# JSON Schema for child objects with different set of keys

Tags: json, jsonschema, json-schema-validator

I have JSON data of which is an array of data like

```
[
  {
    "type": "background_color",
    "data": {
      "backgroundColor": "F9192D"
    }
  },
  {
    "type": "banner_images",
    "data": {
      "images": [
        {
          "url": "https://example.com/abc.jpg",
          "id": 3085
        },
        {
          "url": "https://example.com/zyx.jpg",
          "id": 3086
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  {
    "type": "description_box",
    "data": {
      "text": "Hello 56787"
    }
  }
]
```

The data is an array of object which has two keys `type` and `data`. The type and keys of the `data` will be defined by the `type` of data it has.

Like for `background_color` type, the `data` should have `backgroundColor` property, while for `banner_images`, `data` should have `images` which is an array of other properties.

Till now, What I have done is

```
{
  "definitions": {},
  "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-07/schema#",
  "type": "array",
  "title": "category schema",
  "description": "Used to validate data of category",
  "examples": [],
  "required": [],
  "items": {
    "type": "object",
    "required": [
      "type",
      "data"
    ],
    "properties": {
      "type": {
        "type": "string",
        "enum": ["background_color", "banner_images", "description_box"]
      },
      "data": {
        "type": "object"        // How to define data property here for each use case
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I'm not getting how to define the `data` property for each use case?

Comment: Do you know ALL the possible types up front? If so, I can provide you with an answer =]

Comment: Yes, as per the [documentation](https://json-schema.org/draft/2019-09/json-schema-validation.html#general), they are `null`, `string`, `number`, `array`, `boolean`, `object`, `integer`.

Comment: Sorry, I meant values you want to define as possible types in your data like `banner_images`.

Comment: Yes, I know all the possible types.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `if/then/else` blocks to define conditional constraints.

The values of `if` and `then` are schemas. If the `if` schema is valid, then the `then` schema is applied, otherwise, the `allOf` subschema (`allOf[0]` in this example) would pass validation.

There are a few different ways to do this, but this is clean when you don't have any additional or special requirements. Please come back if you do =]

In this example, I've added `banner_images`...

You can test it working [here](https://jsonschema.dev/s/N4IgziBcLAOgdgAkbEASMBjAFgUwLYCGqkKI2ALhQA6QD0dAVmAPbwC0WeRAdCwE4BzOgBN+hAGYV2ABgDsdLgUIBiVABoEyVBQCe1XCTKF+43Rq1kKASwoAbQ1DKZCFXIIG7ESohaRkRXCx+a2obNiNUAFUwXBFEChZEADdCO2sRV1xETIpCRBYJRBc3D35zEE1-VFsCMCM4f20QPQNIkBYAI0ZcTAo-ZGb+XABHAFdrYZEjAG1LQat9RyqF5tziEHnEAF0VwdRqfhYDfhsghq3m1sdSRtX9lqX2sAoQ+EEB+7JceDH8Wcuq1QnUImAA1oIjmN4CIAPqYFh2ASfL5kEHweC4fiw6xEQTnSqAhaoQLBULheCwzosAAeqCJO0BAF89sSQOsLk0gY82k5UF0en16VzkEytiytqg0nYAPISAEixB3L41eVOZWog5HE5nerqhls66c1H3VAI+AvdrozHY3GEfF6g2DMWKhYu1ES11WPDwY0mrXHLG6v0mgKuDa3J1s4bjSZxBWh00gO0O4WJwa7KMPQ6B07WAmRr2a5N4gtKrNJo18kAmMxp9POiuId2Jlsehltxtc7aWF1MyrJqAgOb+DWLXmkYGgiFQmHwxHIwlcknhkMPEHgyEsaEiADCC-47QAYgBOACMJ4ATAAReui3t7Mc6J7V61YnGlvWssN5NfNFNliOqJjkmYz8HY7SUDQYD0HQuA0oQ+DUA4PAIvgdCEJ0mA8Iw1AfEuoY1NMTgAMwyAAHAArB234LCB3JgRB1ZQdQMEMPBiHIbgqEsOhABeug0jheEoiqybEaQZHkQAbB2gI9lyLaesgT48jcARBJgIRhNYbBUrSokrr++qKjo8H9NWAASuB2EiiCUdJcjkXId7Nr2CDbCATJAA).

```
{
  "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-07/schema#",
  "type": "array",
  "title": "category schema",
  "description": "Used to validate data of category",
  "items": {
    "type": "object",
    "required": [
      "type",
      "data"
    ],
    "properties": {
      "type": {
        "type": "string",
        "enum": [
          "background_color",
          "banner_images",
          "description_box"
        ]
      },
      "data": {
        "type": "object"
      }
    },
    "allOf": [
      {
        "if": {
          "properties": {
            "type": {
              "const": "banner_images"
            }
          }
        },
        "then": {
          "properties": {
            "data": {
              "required": [
                "images"
              ],
              "properties": {
                "images": {
                  "type": "array"
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

For reference, here's the part of the JSON Schema draft-7 spec document that details the behaviour: https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-handrews-json-schema-validation-01#section-6.6

Comment: Thanks Relequestual, Is it possible to validate extra keys in the data which are not allowed. I mean to restrict the keys in an object to the only listed in the schema.

Comment: Welcome. Sure. In the `then` schema, add `"additionalProperties": false`. You may also want to add `"else": false`, but given you already require `type` to be one of the values from the enum, you don't strictly need to add that.